# beautifulsoupで指定した文字列のhrefを含むタグ内の文字列を返したい。

Tags: python

pythonでgoogle検索の結果のなかから最初のwikipediaの項目を調べようとしています。
最終的には検索するタグの中身の『$$$$ - Wikipedia』ような文字列を取得したいです。

```
wikihref = soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^http://ja.wikipedeia.org/'))
```

としても,wikihrefの結果がNoneになってしまいます。stringを要求しているので、結果としてNoneに対してstringが対応していないとattirbutionerrorが出てしまいます。

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        #if link.text
        print(link.text, 'ja.wikipedia.org', link.attrs['href'])
```

こちらのコードだと、ja.wikipedia.orgを含むすべてのタグが表示されるのですが、一つだけというわけにはいかないようです:

下記がコードになります。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import io, sys, urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import GoogleSearch_List as R
import re
import json

base_url = 'https://www.google.com.hk/search?q='

suffix_url = '+wikipedia&ie=UTF-8'

url_list = ['$$$$']

for i in range(len(url_list)):
target_url = base_url + url_list[i] + suffix_url
target_html = requests.get(target_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(target_html, 'html.parser')

#ページタイトル
#print(soup)
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        #if link.text
        print(link.text, 'url?q=https://ja.wikipedia.org', link.attrs['href'])

wikihref = soup.find('a', href=re.compile('^http://ja.wikipedeia.org/'))
print(wikihref)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

正規表現`^http://ja.wikipedeia.org/`は検討の余地があります。

1.タイポ？(wikipedeia -> wikipedia)
2.google検索ではhttpよりもhttpsが返ってくるのではないかということ
3.www.google.com.hkで検索した結果に、ja.wikipedia.orgの結果が含まれるのかということ
4.任意の一文字にマッチする`.`はエスケープして`\.`とするべきではないかということ

これらを考慮した正規表現として、例えば`https?://.+\.wikipedia\.org/`が考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

`ja.wikpedia.org` を含む最初のリンクが取得できればいいんですよね？ 見つかったら breakで forループを終了すればいいんじゃないでしょうか。

```
first_link = None
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    if 'href' in link.attrs and 'ja.wikipedia.org' in link.attrs['href']:
        first_link = link
        break

if first_link:
   print(first_link)
```

また検索してる goolgle の ドメインが「www.google.com.hk」 なので検索結果に `ja.wikipedia.org` がちゃんと出てくるのかはちょっとわかりませんでした。